# Can I convert the font and SVG to base64 via offline OS X and Linux terminals?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, fonts, base64

I know how and I can convert the images to base64 via OS X and Linux terminals.

But I'm not sure if I can convert the fonts and the SVGs to base64 via offline OS X and Linux terminals.

I don't know any offline base64 apps that encode the images, fonts and SVG for OS X and linux. I know Coda 2 has base64 plugin, but it's bug and suffers a fail. TextMate has Emmet plugin that comes with base64 encoder, but I tried and it wasn't converted. Brackets has Emmet too, but Emmet doesn't have base64 plugin. These plugins convert only the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On both systems you can use the `base64` command.

Example:

```
cat test.svg | base64
```

to encode and

```
echo "<base64>" | base64 -d
```

and replace `-d` with `-D` on macOS.

The `base64` utility comes preinstalled on most Linux distros as well as macOS.

Source: https://scottlinux.com/2012/09/01/encode-or-decode-base64-from-the-command-line/

Comment: It appears that `-d` is valid also on macOS:

``` base64 --help
Usage: base64 [-hvDd] [-b num] [-i in_file] [-o out_file]
  -h, --help     display this message
  -Dd, --decode   decodes input
  -b, --break    break encoded string into num character lines
  -i, --input    input file (default: "-" for stdin)
  -o, --output   output file (default: "-" for stdout)```